# VLookup the same person multiple dates

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have two spreadsheets:

[image]

I want to match both sheets and make sure that dates match for every person. E.g. Person 1 has three different dates and I want to match them exactly 1:1.

Person 1, 3/2/2015 (Table A) -> Person 1, 3/2/2015 (Table B)
Person 1, 3/5/2015 (Table A) -> Person 1, 3/5/2015 (Table B)
Person 1, 3/6/2015 (Table A) -> Person 1, 3/6/2015 (Table B)

For the moment I loop through "No." column in Table A and use Application.VLookup on Table B but that only works when a Person has only one date. Otherwise it compares to the first date from Table B. See code:

```
For sheetArowCounter= 2 To sheetAlastRow
    Sheets("A").Select
    sheetAperson = Cells(sheetArowCounter, 1)
    sheetAdate = Cells(sheetArowCounter, 2)
    Sheets("B").Select
    sheetBdate = Application.VLookup(sheetAperson, _
         Sheets("B").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(sheetBLastRow, 2)), 2, False)
    If IsError(sheetBdate ) Then
        personFromTableAnotFound = personFromTableAnotFound + 1
    ElseIf sheetBdate <> sheetAdate Then
        sheetAdateNotMatched = sheetAdateNotMatched + 1
    End If
    sheetAdateCompared = sheetAdateCompared + 1
Next sheetArowCounter
```

Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: Why not simply [SUMIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b) the dates based on the person. If you are missing date(s) or if one is different by so much as a second the difference should be immediately apparent.

Comment: `Sheets(B").Select` missing a double quote

Comment: Or just combine the tables and conditional format - highlight duplicates. You'll see which ones don't match

Comment: Yeah, I used Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("A3:A9"), "Person1", Range("B3:B9")) and it worked like a charm. Thank you very much guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agreed with Jeeped above. Try using a SUMIF. You can even nest the SUMIF in an IF statement to return text: ie: "Match", "No match"

Comment: Yeah, I used Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("A3:A9"), "Person1", Range("B3:B9")) and it worked like a charm. Thank you very much guys

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for a countifs function which can test for criteria against multiple columns. Here is an example for how you could implement this in your code:

```
For sheetArowCounter = 2 To sheetAlastRow
    Sheets("A").Select
    sheetAperson = Cells(sheetArowCounter, 1)
    sheetAdate = Cells(sheetArowCounter, 2)
    Sheets("B").Select

    'using the countifs function eg. =COUNTIFS(B!A3:A11,A!A3,B!B3:B11,A!B3)
    PersonDateMatches = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Sheets("B").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(sheetBLastRow, 1)), sheetAperson, Sheets("B").Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(sheetBLastRow, 2)), sheetAdate)

    If PersonDateMatches = 0 Then
        personDateFromTableAnotFound = personDateFromTableAnotFound + 1
    End If
    sheetAdateCompared = sheetAdateCompared + 1
Next sheetArowCounter
```